# enumitem line separation within a single item

Tags: spacing, lists, enumitem, wrap

I have this happening when the item wraps:

[image]

The code I have so far is:

```
\setlist{leftmargin=!, align=left, font=\large\textsf,
itemsep=20pt, labelwidth=10pt, itemindent=-28pt}
```

How can I adjust the spacing between the two wrapped lines?

Comment: Please make a complete minimal working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) to adjust your line space (or baseline skip):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[IUI-10] IUI must display a warning if the Route will pass through an unmanaged Sector
    during the shift
  \item[IUI-10] IUI must display a warning if the Route will pass through an unmanaged Sector
    during the shift
  \item[IUI-10] IUI must display a warning if the Route will pass through an unmanaged Sector
    during the shift
\end{itemize}

\setstretch{2}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[IUI-10] IUI must display a warning if the Route will pass through an unmanaged Sector
    during the shift
  \item[IUI-10] IUI must display a warning if the Route will pass through an unmanaged Sector
    during the shift
  \item[IUI-10] IUI must display a warning if the Route will pass through an unmanaged Sector
    during the shift
\end{itemize}
\end{document}​
```

The above is (or should be) independent of [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) since it involves paragraph settings and not necessarily lists.

Comment: cheers, awesome!